# ADFS 2.0 Default Home Realm

Tags: adfs2.0, adfs

What is the best way to customize ADFS to use a specific, configurable home realm if one was not provided?

My current method is to perform an HTTP redirect from the ADFS WebForms aspx file, but that seems a bit hackish.

I don't want my Relying Parties to be concerned with the home realms.

Comment: i've actually been wondering myself about this and would be curious to see if anyone's done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a good approach would be to add a few lines within the ADFS HomeRealmDiscovery page in order to read the "*DefaultHomeRealm*" setting from the ADFS web.config file.

**Steps**

1. Go to C:\inetpub\adfs\ls
2. Open the **HomeRealmDiscovery.aspx.cs**
3. In the **Page_Init** method, add something like:

   if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultHomeRealm"] != null)
   {
     **SelectHomeRealm**(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultHomeRealm"]);
   }
4. Open the **web.config** file
5. On the **appSettings** section, add:

   add key="DefaultHomeRealm" value="Default ADFS Federation Service Identifier"

*Do not forget to replace the service URI that you want to be defaulted.*

For more information you can check:

- [SelectHomeRealm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identityserver.web.ui.homerealmdiscoverypage.selecthomerealm.aspx) method
- [ADFS pages customization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895356.aspx)

I have successfully used this approach.

I hope it helps :)

Seba

Comment: Best answer so far.  I was hoping this would be a setting in ADFS.  This is much cleaner than my redirect and appending whr, so if I don't get something else soon, I'll toss my bounty here.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

[Windows Identity Foundation (WIF): How to Utilize the WS-Federation WHR Parameter to Bypass Home Realm Discovery (HRD)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2424.windows-identity-foundation-wif-how-to-utilize-the-ws-federation-whr-parameter-to-bypass-home-realm-discovery-hrd.aspx).

The WS-Federation passive WHR parameter is used to bypass home realm discovery (HRD)

Comment: So you're on the right track.  I *do* want to bypass HRD, but due to the nature of my implementation, the Relying Parties won't/can't know about the home realm.  I need something on the ADFS side such that when a WHR is not provided, then instead of using its own authentication, it goes to some default Home Realm that I specify.